# Elixir equivalent of TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)

Tags: elixir

If I want to specify an amount of time in C# (for example in a timer) I'd say `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)`. It's explicit...a bit verbose, but there's no question about the length of time I'm specifying.

What's "the Elixir way" to accomplish the same thing?  I could say `1_000 * 20` but that's *implied*, not explicit. There's no clear way to specify. I'm referring to seconds, microseconds, or even referring to time at all.

Comment: `~T[00:00:20.000]` seems to be the way to denote 20 seconds in Elixir.

Comment: @IllidanS4wantsMonicaback not at all. `~T[00:00:20.000]` is a way to specify 20 seconds past midnight time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elixir doesn't have a built-in duration/time-span type.

There is [`Timex.Duration`](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/Timex.Duration.html), but it's probably best to avoid adding Timex to your dependencies if you can get by with standard library code.

For working with interfaces that expect milliseconds, there are some built-in functions in the [`:timer`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html) module to return milliseconds.

```
iex(1)> :timer.seconds(20)
20000
iex(2)> :timer.minutes(2)
120000
iex(3)> :timer.hours(4)
14400000
```

Answer (score 2):

There is neither *seconds* not *microseconds* type in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir). That said, the value in the vacuum cannot be “in seconds,” it’s just an integer.

Time fractions make sense only when you do math with times, and all the respective functions have an argument that allows you to specify it explicitly.

Consider [`Time.add/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Time.html#add/3) function, that adds a specified amount *of time fractions* to the time instance.

Here you explicitly specify the fraction to add.

```rb
iex(1)> t = Time.utc_now()       
#⇒ ~T[20:37:01.699735]
iex(2)> Time.add(t, 20, :second)
#⇒ ~T[20:37:21.699735]
```

Comment: to get time interval `Time.add(~T[00:00:00], 20, :second)`

Comment: @Kuanysh `Time.add/2` returns **time instance**, not time interval.